# Match Text Colour to Randomly Selected Background Colour (PHP Array)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, colors, background

I'm building a Wordpress site that has a randomly selected background colour.

[The site can be seen here.](http://www.broken-culture.co.uk/ChecktheRhyme/)

The way I've done the random bg colour is with a php array (see below for the function).

```
function random_bg() {
    $bgs = array ('FF8400', 'F7F7F7', '00C6FF', 'FF3D3D', '00E4B6', 'FFE063', 'AE00FF', '888888', '91d8ac', '7ce5ee', 'eeca7c', 'eea27c', 'e28989', 'f79090', '94ecd4', 'ffa92e', 'aaedb4', '5dbee2', 'e24343', 'e2ac43', '70acef');
    $n = rand( 0, 20);
    echo $bgs[$n];
}
```

Now, I'd like to make the links in the footer change colour in order to match whichever background colour is randomly selected. Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Max.

Comment: Give inline style with selected background into your div.

Comment: @Rikesh Hi Rikesh, thanks! Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean though, I know the div selector for that footer etc, but how would I specify it to detect which random bg colour has been selected through css?

Any chance you can provide an example of that css? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
function random_colors() {
    $bgs = array ('FF8400', 'F7F7F7', '00C6FF', 'FF3D3D', '00E4B6', 'FFE063', 'AE00FF', '888888', '91d8ac', '7ce5ee', 'eeca7c', 'eea27c', 'e28989', 'f79090', '94ecd4', 'ffa92e', 'aaedb4', '5dbee2', 'e24343', 'e2ac43', '70acef');
    $fgs = array (etc...)
    $n = rand( 0, 20);
    return array($bgs[$n], $fgs[$n];
}

$color = random_colors();

$background = $color[0];
$foreground = $color[1];
```

Now in the HTML

```
<body style="background:<?php echo $background; ?>">

    <footer style="background:<?php echo $foreground; ?>">Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Pez. Although that php function produces an error:

' Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/brokencu/public_html/ChecktheRhyme/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/functions.php on line 553'

Comment: I'm leaving you to figure that one out!